# magento send order confirmation email after sucess payment

Tags: email, magento, paypal, credit-card

i have a problem. everytime someone order a product and pay with creditcard or paypal - the additional checkout field are empty in the conformation email.

i think this is because the extern payment system are not finish. how i can manage that the order confirmation email is sending after sucess payment?

do you have a solution for this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things.  The most likely being that you recently applied SUPEE-6788 to your store and that you need to whitelist template variables.  Here is a link to a tool that can help you: https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox